# Laravel - Redirect with both data and message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

This is my categories list page.

[image]

To load this page Controller code is

```
public function categorysettings(Request $request)
{
  $categorieslist=productcategory::all();
  return view('categorieslist',compact('categorieslist'));
}
```

now when i click delete button this code is executed.

```
public function deletecategory($categoryid)
{
   $category = productcategory::find($categoryid);
   $category->delete();
   $categorieslist=productcategory::all();
   return Redirect::back()->with('deleted','Successfully Deleted Category !!!');

}
```

In my html page i have session names as deleted to display the message.
But whenever i click delete button the data gets deleted but it show like this.
[image]

Any Help or suggestion are most welcome.

As per request my view file code is below.Thank you.

```
    @if(Session::has('deleted'))
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    {{Session::get('deleted')}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
```

Comment: arrays are cool

Comment: can you post/include your view file's code where you display the `deleted` session message?

Comment: added the view file code.

Comment: `->with(["deleted" => "This is your deleted message"]);`, or you could use `session()->flash("deleted", "This is your deleted message.");`

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: maybe your session storage is not working or not configured properly, make sure your `app/config/session.php`'s `'driver' => 'file'` settings is correct, if you're using `file` as the value, then make sure the `'files' => storage_path().'/sessions',` actual directory is writable.

Comment: You should try using findOrFail: `$category = productcategory::findOrFail($categoryid);`.  As is your code assumes that a valid id was passed in, but those ids are user input as much as anything else.

Comment: The code is working for me...

Comment: @bubjavier 
I am using laravel 5.2
In my session.php file the codes are
 'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file')
'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

Answer (score 1):

Define deleted variable in session

```
public function deletecategory($categoryid)
{
   $category = productcategory::find($categoryid);
   $category->delete();
   $categorieslist=productcategory::all();
   session()->flash('deleted', 'Successfully Deleted Category !!!');
   return Redirect::back();
}
```

Check session document in laravel website https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#flash-data

Comment: The same output is obtained.

Comment: Can you please do `dd(session()->all());` and paste result here ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
In Your controller
return redirect()->back()->with('deleted', 'Successfully Deleted Category !!!');
```

And in view file

```
@if(Session::has('deleted'))
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {!! session('deleted') !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
public function deletecategory($categoryid)
{
   $category = productcategory::find($categoryid);
   $category->delete();
   $categorieslist=productcategory::all();
   return redirect(<Category-list-route>)
       ->with('success', 'Successfully Deleted Category !!!');
}
```

Then in the blade

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                {{Session::get('success')}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
@if(Session::get('deleted'))
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                {{Session::get('deleted')}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: The Same result is obtained.

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller Write these code

```
Session::flash('deleted', 'Category information deleted successfully.');
return Redirect::to('/your-category-list-url'); 
// Your Listing page which you wrote in web.php under routes folder if you are using laravel 5.4
// If you are using laravel 5.2 then in your routes.php
```

Now In your blade template

```
@if(Session::has('deleted'))
<div class="col-lg-10 pull-right" align="center">
    <div class="alert alert-danger  alert-dismissable " role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>  <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  {{ Session::get('deleted') }}
    </div>
</div>
@endif
```

Make sure you use these in your controller

```
use Session;
use Redirect;
```

I hope this will work for you